# How to modify a readonly field in a value-type after construction

Tags: c#

From C# 4.0 Section 7.5.5.

> If M is an instance function member declared in a value-type:
>
> - [...]
> - If E is not classified as a variable, then a temporary local variable of E's type is created and the value of E is assigned to the
>     variable.  E is then reclassified as a reference to that temporary
>     local variable.  The temporary variable is accessible as this within
>     M, but not in any other way.  Thus, only when E is a **true variable**
>     (*what is a true variable...?*) is it possible for the caller to observe the changes that
>     M makes to this.

Eric Lippert goes on to say:

> This point illustrates yet another way in which the combination of
>   mutability and copy-by-value semantics can lead to trouble.  For
>   example, a readonly field is not classified as a variable after the
>   constructor runs.  Therefore, an attempt to call a method that mutates
>   the contents of a readonly field of a value type succeeds but actually
>   mutates a copy!  Avoid these problems by avoiding mutable value types
>   altogether.

How can I reproduce the scenerio described by Eric?  I tried the following. It Errors out as I would expect:

```
    struct A
    {
        public readonly int mutableReadonlyField;

        public A(int originalValue)
        {
            mutableReadonlyField = originalValue;
        }

        public A MethodThatMutatesTheContentsOfAReadOnlyField(int mutate)
        {            
            this.mutableReadonlyField = mutate;//Constructor has run so mutableReadonlyField is a temporary local variable
            //ERROR: A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)

            A newA = this;//Is this a true variable?
            return newA;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I give an example of this on my blog:

http://ericlippert.com/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/

The problem is that my sentence fragment "a readonly field of a value type" is ambiguous and misleading. I intended it to mean a readonly field in a *class* where the field is of *value type S*, but obviously the more natural reading is to take it as a readonly field *in S itself*. I should have recast the sentence entirely. Apologies for the error.

To answer your other question: the adjective "true" is unnecessary. The sentence would be equally correct if it just said "Thus, only when E is a variable is it possible for the caller to observe the changes that M makes to this.

Comment: It seems to me that in general readonly and mutable types are a bad combination.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Correct. This is a special case of the more general rule that X and mutable types are a bad combination for all values of X.